# how to get Last updated Record in sql server

Tags: sql

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table with 5 records. The table does **not** have any column that keeps track of LastUpdated or something like that.

Is it possible to find out when was the last date/time that someone added/changed a record? Which record was that?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us what is _has_. Apart from that add a column `LastUpdated` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In General Practice you should add column to do this ,But any ways you can see the last time the table was Modified

if you want to check the `Structure Modiifcation`

USE

`SELECT * FROM SYS.Tables where Name Like '[TableName]'`

Here Column `Modify_Date` will give you last time table was modified

if you want to check the `Data Modiifcation`

USE

`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( '[YourDatabaseName]')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the latest modification datetime on that table then use

```
Select modify_date from sys.tables where name = 'tablename'
```

If you want to know the particular record then there is no way you have to use :

```
 Alter table tablename add modifieddate datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

select t.name, user_seeks, user_scans, user_lookups, user_updates, last_user_seek, last_user_scan, last_user_lookup, last_user_update
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats i JOIN sys.tables t ON (t.object_id = i.object_id)
where database_id = db_id()

Comment: Please provide a description